# Select only numbers after certain substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple rows that contains a string with different values, some of them have numbers, like this one:

```
XARELTO 20 MG 14 COM.(A)(P)85003(SC)(SF)
```

I need to get the numbers on the string, but only the ones that are right after "(P)", so that I will get:

```
85003
```

Ignoring all the chars before (P) and after the number 85003

For example, this are some of the rows:

```
| ProductName                                  |
+----------------------------------------------+
| VALCOTE 125 MG 30 CAP.(P)15188(SC)(SF)       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| ALPHAGAN SOL. OFT. 5 ML (A)(P)19347(SC)      |
+----------------------------------------------+
| LUMIGAN 0.03% OF.3ML(A)(P)67740(SC)(3%+)     |
+----------------------------------------------+
| BETALOC ZOK 50 MG 30 TBS (P)15390            |
+----------------------------------------------+
| CASODEX 50 MGS 28 TBS (E)(P)104334(SC)       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| SEROQUEL 100 MG 30 TBS(E)(A)(P)55800         |
+----------------------------------------------+
| SEROQUEL 200 MG 30 TBS (E)(A)(P)111600       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| SEROQUEL 25 MG 30 TBS (A)(P)13950            |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

And this is what I need after the SELECT statement:

```
| ProductPrice                                 |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 15188                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 19347                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 67740                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 15390                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 104334                                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 55800                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 111600                                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 13950                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Ideally, you need to fix your design. You shouldn't be storing data with multiple different bits of information in a single column. They should all be stored in a destinct column and/or row.

Comment: Learning proper database design should be the first step you should do.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty, but it works. This doesn't assume, however, that all values will have 5 characters:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('VALCOTE 125 MG 30 CAP.(P)15188(SC)(SF)  '),
                ('ALPHAGAN SOL. OFT. 5 ML (A)(P)19347(SC) '),
                ('LUMIGAN 0.03% OF.3ML(A)(P)67740(SC)(3%+)'),
                ('BETALOC ZOK 50 MG 30 TBS (P)15390       '),
                ('CASODEX 50 MGS 28 TBS (E)(P)104334(SC)  '),
                ('SEROQUEL 100 MG 30 TBS(E)(A)(P)55800    '),
                ('SEROQUEL 200 MG 30 TBS (E)(A)(P)111600  '),
                ('SEROQUEL 25 MG 30 TBS (A)(P)13950       '))V(ProductName))
SELECT V.ProductName,
       LEFT(S.R,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(',S.R),0)-1,LEN(S.R))) AS ProductPrice
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%(P)%',V.ProductName)))PI(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(V.ProductName,1,PI.I+2,'')))S(R);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data, the numbers all have five digits.  That suggests:

```
select left(stuff(str, 1, patindex('%(P)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', str) + 2, ''), 5)
from (values ('XARELTO 20 MG 14 COM.(A)(P)85003(SC)(SF)')) v(str);
```

SQL Server is not great at processing strings.  This can be modified to handle a variable number of digits, but the expression is a bit more complicated.

EDIT:

Here is the version for arbitrary lengths:

```
select left(v.str + ' ', patindex('%[^0-9]%', v.str + ' ') - 1)
from (values ('XARELTO 20 MG 14 COM.(A)(P)85003(SC)(SF)'),
             ('SEROQUEL 200 MG 30 TBS (E)(A)(P)111600')
     ) x(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(x.str, 1, patindex('%(P)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', x.str) + 2, ''))) v(str);
```

Comment: *"In your sample data, the numbers all have five digits."* They don't, take a look at the 5th and 7th examples; they have 6 digits.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I like my eyesight better ;)